# Windows Authentication in Chrome/Edge got issue HTTP request is unauthorized...the authentication header received from the server was Nogotitate, NTLM

Tags: google-chrome, wcf, microsoft-edge, ntlm-authentication, http-negotiate

I have an issue with a web client calls to WCF service.

[image: Error Message]

The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme "Negotiate". The authentication header received from the server was "Negotiate, NTLM"...

I can say that all of the staff in the company do not face this issue except the staff in Germany.

And the interested thing is, when I ask staff in Germany tried to browse the web site with new Incognito tab, he inputed his windows authentication and it worked...but normal Chrome/Edge does not work....Firefox works perfectly.

And a weird thing is when he browsed the website in firefox, for example

http://test.com/abc.html

He came back to Chrome/Edge, tried to browse http://test.com/abc.html --> it works :)) even before that it does not work in Chrome/Edge...sounds like he has to warm up an url with Firefox before browsing that url with Chrome/Edge...

I asked him to clean up his Chrome and it does not work too. I don't think it's because of the website or wcf configuration because it's been working very well for a long time and many people is using it normally except German guys.

Does anyone ever face this issue or could you kindly give me some idea to resolve this issue?

Many thanks,

Comment: This issue may be a Chrome/Edge compatibility issue, you can try debugging.

Comment: @Jiayao we use the same chrome/edge version with German people but only German people have this issue and it has just happened last week...

Comment: Collect the bug log file and send it to the official to see if there is any solution

Comment: @Jiayao where can I find the bug log file? and what do you mean "send it to the official"?

Comment: Sorry.There's something wrong with my expression.You can start by looking for the log file that reported the error and  upload the complete bug file to : [https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/)